# What are the ways to check 24 hours are completed?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, alarmmanager, timertask

In my application I have to check whether the 24 hours are completed.
How do I check such things using Thread, TimerTask and Alaram Manager.

Let me know how do I achieve this thing using TIMERTASK and THREAD ?

Comment: How about `current time + 24 hours` ? :)

Comment: [Alarm manager](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/android-notification-with-sound-and-icon-tutorial.html) with pending intent to be triggered after 24 hours.

Comment: yes suresh whether 24 hours are completed or not.

Comment: How can I do that Dhruti can you tell me ? Can I send broadcast when 24 hours are completed How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I have added reference link. Please refer that.

Comment: yes, SURESH ATTA...E.g. Say I started my application at 8 :00 AM in today's date and completed at tomorrow's 8:00 AM so How can I calculate with TimerTask or Alarm Manager or Are there any ways to check this and how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Alarm Manager:

#### A small example:

**This is working code. It wakes CPU every 10 minutes until the phone turns off.**

Add to Manifest.xml:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
...
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>
...
```

Code:

```
    package YourPackage;
    import android.app.AlarmManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.PowerManager;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {    
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
         {   
             PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
             PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
             wl.acquire();

             // Put here YOUR code.
             Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

             wl.release();
         }

     public void SetAlarm(Context context)
     {
         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     }

     public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
     {
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.cancel(sender);
     }
 }
```

**Set Alarm from Service:**

```
package YourPackage;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class YourService extends Service
{
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();       
    }

    public void onStart(Context context,Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        alarm.SetAlarm(context);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**If you want set alarm repeating at phone boot time:**

Add permission to Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
...
<receiver android:name=".AutoStart">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
...
```

And create new class:

```
package YourPackage;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {   
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            alarm.SetAlarm(context);
        }
    }
}
```

### Alarms work in a different manner on and after API 19, make sure you are using API 18 and below if you want this to work. Otherwise you can include methods for API 19 from the official Docs.

Comment: Thanks I will check .. Byzantine Failure above code which checks for 24 hours are completed or not. Right ?

Comment: The above will do for each 10 minutes, you can modify it. Please make sure you take care of wakelocks if you use any. Release them in time.

Comment: And also let me know how to check with TimerTask  whether the 24 hours are completed.

Comment: I will not advise to use a timer task, it will keep your CPU busy for the entire time. That means stress for the battery.

Comment: yes, I am implementing this thing in Android Application SPECIFY. so let me know if i have to check for 24 hours are completed then can you tell me where do I change above code please ?  Thanks your suggestions and understand my problem too..

Comment: and yes we are using the API 18 .

Comment: CHange `am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute` to `am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*60*24, pi);`

Comment: Let me check this thing.

Comment: Hi I have used this code but i didnt get proper solutions.

Comment: Pans you can post a new question about what you expected and what you got. Lot of Alarm Manager API has changed, so please check with the docs again. Alarms work different below and above API 19

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether 24 hours has passed since last time, from inside app, I use sharedpreference by storing last time this check passed,

```
    long hourSince1970 = System.currentTimeMillis()/3600000;
    long lastUpdatedHour = MySharedPreference.getTimeLastUpdated(); // defaults to 0

    if(lastUpdatedHour == 0 || hourSince1970-lastUpdatedHour >= 24){
        MySharedPreference.setTimeLastUpdated(hourSince1970);
        // 24 hours passed
        // do your thing
    }
```

Comment: Hi can anyone please tell me How do I achieve this thing using  
TIMER TASK and THREAD because as per my requirement.